# Browser does not recognize javascript logical operator

Tags: javascript

I'm having to run an if with 2 conditions, but javascript does not recognize the && character, nor when I put & amp;

Does anyone know how to make xhtml recognize?
Follow the code below

```
if(chave = '0' && minutos >= 60){
console.log("if");
}
```

Comment: what kind of condition it is chave='0' , what about chave=='0'?

Comment: What do you mean by *"does not recognize"*?

Comment: Works just as expected -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6yx11c7r/, assignment returns the assigned value, and a string is true.

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in the title here. If you answered your own question you can post and accept it, or delete the question.

Comment: Worked once,
Again the same error

Comment: Javascript does not recognize the && characters

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to compare something by equality, you need to use `==` or `===` for strict equality. When you write `chave = '0'`, it means that you assign the string `'0'` to variable `chave`. Here is the basic working snippet with some tests:

```js
function checkIfStatement(chave, minutos) {
  if(chave == '0' && minutos >= 60){
    console.log("'If' WORKS with parameters chave: " + chave + ", minutos: " + minutos);
  } else {
    console.log("'If' DOESN'T WORK with parameters chave: " + chave + ", minutos: " + minutos);
  }
}

checkIfStatement(0, 60);
checkIfStatement(0, 59);
checkIfStatement(1, 60);
```

Comment: Javascript does not recognize if with two conditions. It gives the following error: The content of the elements must consist of data or mark the correct character

Comment: @GustavoMenezes, why? In my example, Javascript checks `chave == '0'` first, and then, if it's evaluates to `true`, checks  `minutos >= 60`. `checkIfStatement(0, 60);`: first and second evaluates to `true`. `checkIfStatement(0, 59);`: first evaluates to `true`, second evaluates to `false`. `checkIfStatement(1, 60);`: first evaluates to `false`, second wasn't checked (because first statement is `false`).

Comment: @GustavoMenezes, "The content of the elements must consist of data or mark the correct character". Did you declare `chave` and `minutos` variables in your code via `var`, `let` or `const`?

Comment: Variables are declared.
The problem that is happening is that charset can not recognize the && character.
When I remove the second condition, if it works.